# How to mapping a struct EnumerableSet.AddressSet / UintSet?

Tags: solidity, remix

Hello guys I want to make mapping but got some issues.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol";
contract fNftErc20 {
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.UintSet;

    struct fCollection{
        EnumerableSet.AddressSet nftAddress;
        EnumerableSet.UintSet nftIds;
        bool mintable;
    }

    mapping(address => fCollection) private fractionalizationCollections;

    function ad(address fnft, address[] calldata nft, uint256[] calldata id) public {
      EnumerableSet.AddressSet lockedNft;
      EnumerableSet.UintSet lockedId;
      for(uint256 i = 0; i<nft.length; i++){
        lockedId.add(id[i]);
        lockedNft.add(nft[i]);
      }
      fractionalizationCollections[fnft] = fCollection(lockedNft, lockedId, true);
    }
}
```

I want make something like this but dont know how make it true. If someone got idea please share with, thanks so much)))

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are encountering are because you cannot assign a struct containing (nested) mappings directly, and you cannot construct a struct containing (nested) mappings.

Additionally `lockedNft` and `lockedId` cannot be declared locally i.e. in `memory` since `AddressSet` and `UintSet` contain mappings, and so while they can be moved into contract state i.e. `storage` since this would be gas heavy you can instead add the nft address and id onto a given `fCollection` as shown below.

In short, to fix these issues, you can update your contract by removing the direct assignments and constructors for the `fCollection` struct, and instead use a two-step process to update the mappings inside the struct. Here's the updated contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/structs/EnumerableSet.sol";

contract fNftErc20 {
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.UintSet;

    struct fCollection {
        EnumerableSet.AddressSet nftAddress;
        EnumerableSet.UintSet nftIds;
        bool mintable;
    }

    mapping(address => fCollection) private fractionalizationCollections;

    function ad(address fnft, address[] calldata nft, uint256[] calldata id) public {
        // Check if the fCollection does not exist for the given fnft address
        require(
            !fractionalizationCollections[fnft].mintable,
            "fCollection already exists for the given fnft address"
        );

        // Initialize the fCollection for the given fnft address
        fractionalizationCollections[fnft].mintable = true;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < nft.length; i++) {
            fractionalizationCollections[fnft].nftIds.add(id[i]);
            fractionalizationCollections[fnft].nftAddress.add(nft[i]);
        }
    }
}
```